# small file cause OutofMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, deserialization

I have an encrypted file which I decrypt first and then try to deserialize it using `memorystream` and `binaryformatter` but when I try to assign deserialized files to a list I catch `OutOfMemoryException` (file is really small - 17KB)
here is the code

```
byte[] encryptedData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName); 
byte[] result = Decrypt(Algo, key, vector, encryptedData) ;
BinaryFormatter ser = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result)) {
 try {
     files = ser.Deserialize(ms) as List<IItem>;
  } catch (OutOfMemoryException) {

  } catch (SerializationException) {
     MessageBox.Show("Incorrect password!");
     return;
  }
}
```

`files = ser.Deserialize(ms) as List<IItem>;` - this what cause exception 
encrypted file size 1696
after decryption 1691 - normal size.
here Decryption code

```
public byte[] Decode(byte[] data)
    {
        string key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(rc2.Key);
        string IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(rc2.IV);
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rc2.CreateDecryptor(rc2.Key,rc2.IV);
        StringBuilder roundtrip = new StringBuilder();
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                int b = 0;

                do
                {
                    b = csDecrypt.ReadByte();

                    if (b != -1)
                    {
                        roundtrip.Append((char) b);
                    }
                } while (b != -1);
            }
        }
        byte[] decrypted = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(roundtrip.ToString());
        return decrypted;
    }
```

Comment: What is the memory consumption of your application at the moment when `OutofMemoryException` was thrown? Also which environment you're in? Mobile app or desktop? x86 or x64?

Comment: about 12-13MB. enviroment MVS, desktop app, x86

Comment: Can you print out `ms.Length` (or check it in the debugger)? Deserialize to an object first and then look at the actual type in the debugger (mouse-over and see type, or in the watch, use the variable.GetType() function).

Comment: What does Decrypt do? It could take a 17KB file and turn it into 17GB... Look at the length of result.

Comment: Decrypt just Decrypts encrypted bytes by picked algorith( ofcourse algorithm is similar by whichi it was crypted ) and returns 'byte[]' it's smaller then entry bytes I mean  encrypted array size is 16896 and after decryption 16891

Comment: The problem may be that the bytes that you have decrypted are not valid, and able to be deserialized appropriately. Did you write this file yourself? Can you check that results equals the original output of Serialize? What is the need for the StringBuilder - why can't you just get the bytes of the csDecrypt?

Comment: BinaryFormatter produces *bytes* when it serializes an object.  You cannot convert bytes to characters, not all possible byte values are a valid Unicode codepoint.  Especially bad when you use ASCII, it can only represent values between 0 and 127.  So the data you decrypt is inevitably corrupted, BinaryFormatter is going to throw a fit.  You need to *only* work with bytes, remove the code that converts to characters on both the encryption and decryption parts of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MineR and @HansPassant was right problem was in using chars while decrypting)) i have changed my code

```
       public byte[] Decode(byte[] data)
    {
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rc2.CreateDecryptor(rc2.Key,rc2.IV);
        byte[] decrypted = new byte[data.Length];
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
               csDecrypt.Read(decrypted, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
```

and now it works. Thx all for answers.